# Writing a web handler to return profile images?

Tags: asp.net, security

The main website has a profile page. I save the profile images in an "Images" folder, I guess that was a bad idea. So now I moved the Images folder to App_Data so that now no remote access is allowed to that folder(More security and privacy). So, my code now calls a service called ServiceImages having a method called getimages which is passed a username. So what it does is, it returns the image named "username"+extension(I save the image with the username's name). But, then remote tools can be used to hack and get all the images by using permutations of alphabets and numbers as username to get the image and save it. That's certainly not the thing I want. At least, not make it that easy to get all profile Images. So how can I restrict access to such automated tools? Is using IP check a good Idea and how to do that? I don't want the images to be saved in the database. Isn't there some other elegant way, that I can block such automated hacking tools or scripts? I don't want my website to be making news it was hacked.

Comment: Well in case you can delegate that task to an external application, take a loot to gravatar (http://gravatar.com/)

Comment: @Jupaol Cannot do that. It needs to be us storing and serving the images, cannot externalize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting images in app_data, or a subfolder of that only stops direct browser. What you have is a kind of "insecure direct object reference". So what you need to do is swap to an indirect object reference, use, for example a GUID for the file name of the profile picture rather than username.jpg, and then when you want to request the file for a user look up the user -> guid from a mapping table.

Of course this doesn't stop anyone going through every single GUID, but, well, that will take a rather long time. You could be sneaky and if an IP address has x number of failed lookups in y minutes halt all requests from them for z amount of time, that's easy enough to do inside your handler.

But really, is it worth it? Getting profile pictures is hardly a hack, unless you only want the profile pictures to be limited to users who are logged in - in which case just put them in a directory which doesn't allow anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO: I dont think in your current setup there is any way to restrict IP address since you still have to serve profile images based on the client request for authorized users.

The App_Data folder is designed to store databases, xml data. I don't think it is good idea to store user images in App_Data. You can always have Images Folder and secure the folder location by disabling directory browsing on that folder.

I think that you need a better way to name your profile images to avoid brute force/permutation-combinations of image name. 
I prefer some kind Unique Key of GUID or a random combination of characters/number mapped to UserName  and store that Key in database.This will require you to perform 1 time conversion of images name to that unique key and store those keys to database.

However you serve profile images (directly using http path or dynamically using handler), you need a strong file name which is hard to guess using brute force methods.